# How to choose the initramfs source files with buildroot and Nios2 FPGA

Tags: linux, fpga, boot, intel-fpga, nios

I built latest version of [Linux from Altera](https://github.com/altera-opensource) for my Altera DE2-115 FPGA. It won't boot properly because of something with the file system. Maybe you know what I should do? I suppose it is some option in `make menuconfig` but I don't know what do to.

```
Linux version 4.9.0-00104-g84d4f8a-dirty (developer@1604) (gcc version 6.2.0 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2016.11-32) ) #28 Wed Apr 5 04:23:07 CEST 2017
bootconsole [early0] enabled
early_console initialized at 0xe8001440
On node 0 totalpages: 32768
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c022166c, node_mem_map c0254b80
  Normal zone: 256 pages used for memmap
  Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
  Normal zone: 32768 pages, LIFO batch:7
pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
Kernel command line: debug console=ttyAL0,115200
PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 127528K/131072K available (1750K kernel code, 66K rwdata, 284K rodata, 76K init, 191K bss, 3544K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS:64 nr_irqs:64 0
clocksource: nios2-clksrc: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 38225208935 ns
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 100.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=50000)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
cpu cpu0: Error -2 creating of_node link
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275000 ns
random: fast init done
clocksource: Switched to clocksource nios2-clksrc
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=15 bucket_order=0
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 254)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
8001440.serial: ttyJ0 at MMIO 0x8001440 (irq = 2, base_baud = 0) is a Altera JTAG UART
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
List of all partitions:
No filesystem could mount root, tried: 
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
random: crng init done
```

[image]

I found the option in menuconfig and now I get a different error:

```
Linux version 4.9.0-00104-g84d4f8a-dirty (developer@1604) (gcc version 6.2.0 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2016.11-32) ) #37 Wed Apr 5 11:23:36 CEST 2017
bootconsole [early0] enabled
early_console initialized at 0xe8001440
On node 0 totalpages: 32768
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c03cf6b0, node_mem_map c0402b80
  Normal zone: 256 pages used for memmap
  Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
  Normal zone: 32768 pages, LIFO batch:7
pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
Kernel command line: debug console=ttyAL0,115200
PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 125808K/131072K available (1775K kernel code, 67K rwdata, 288K rodata, 1768K init, 191K bss, 5264K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS:64 nr_irqs:64 0
clocksource: nios2-clksrc: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 38225208935 ns
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 100.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=50000)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
cpu cpu0: Error -2 creating of_node link
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275000 ns
random: fast init done
clocksource: Switched to clocksource nios2-clksrc
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=15 bucket_order=0
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 254)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
8001440.serial: ttyJ0 at MMIO 0x8001440 (irq = 2, base_baud = 0) is a Altera JTAG UART
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1768K (c01bd000 - c0377000)
This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100

---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100

random: crng init done
```

[image]

Now I select the directory of my buildroot files,

```
~$ ls -ahl /home/developer/nios2/buildroot/output/images/
total 9,6M
drwxr-xr-x 2 developer developer 4,0K apr  5 07:56 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 developer developer 4,0K apr  5 07:33 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 developer developer 3,7M apr  5 07:56 rootfs.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 developer developer 2,1M apr  5 07:56 rootfs.jffs2
-rw-r--r-- 1 developer developer 3,8M apr  5 07:56 rootfs.tar
```

then I get this output

```
Linux version 4.9.0-00104-g84d4f8a-dirty (developer@1604) (gcc version 6.2.0 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2016.11-32) ) #40 Wed Apr 5 11:35:15 CEST 2017
bootconsole [early0] enabled
early_console initialized at 0xe8001440
On node 0 totalpages: 32768
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c07736b0, node_mem_map c07a6b80
  Normal zone: 256 pages used for memmap
  Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
  Normal zone: 32768 pages, LIFO batch:7
�pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
Kernel command line: debug console=ttyAL0,115200
PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
�Memory: 122080K/131072K available (1775K kernel code, 67K rwdata, 288K rodata, 5496K init, 191K bss, 8992K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS:64 nr_irqs:64 0
clocksource: nios2-clksrc: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 38225208935 ns
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 100.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=50000)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
cpu cpu0: Error -2 creating of_node link
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275000 ns
random: fast init done
clocksource: Switched to clocksource nios2-clksrc
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=15 bucket_order=0
random: crng init done
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 254)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
8001440.serial: ttyJ0 at MMIO 0x8001440 (irq = 2, base_baud = 0) is a Altera JTAG UART
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
Failed to create /dev/root: -2
List of all partitions:
No filesystem could mount root, tried: 
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first, please note that the instruction of rocketboard wiki page isn't complete. To recompile the Nios2's kernel is not so easy task, because it has many bugs, insufficient instructions and confusions of maintainers themselves. Secondly,  Linux kernel itself is a quite huge software. You need miscellaneous knowledge, including ancient (for example virtual terminal tty0) technique.  So, it is a fantasy to think that the command 'make menuconfig' and  'make' will do everything well. Please think seriously the above answer 'Where is your initrd?'.

Comment: How can I ever know if you only answer with questions? I googled about initrd and the information is not complete and the info is different everywhere

Comment: Haven't you already succeeded to boot the old version (ver2.6.34?) and used initrd? Please see your menuconfig and the settings.

And Mr. Flexo, please mind your own bussiness.

Comment: ＞Now I read 350 lines of documentation about initrd and nothing is instructions how to make it. 

Are you reading this document 'Linux/Documentation/initrd.txt'?

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/initrd.txt?v=4.9

This document describes the role and internals of initrd fs and, does not describe the making procedure.  

> The writers are deliberately making a sabotage for the reader.

As is often the case with Linux, many documents are written in past and obsolete. So sometimes, the source code itself is the best instruction.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found in menuconfig an option to set the files for the initrd but when I boot the system it becomes kernel panic. I updated my question with my findings.

Comment: The first kernel panic 

'Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100'

means that the init task is aborted (with some error) and the kernel can't continue the booting. The task 'init' is the parent task for all, and we can't kill it.

The second kernel panic 

'Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0, 0)'

means that the kernel can't mount the root file system again. So this second problem is worse than first one.

Comment: Problem definition is good to have. I tried in menuconfig choosing the three image files that were output from buildroot. I set the name of the directory and then it was kernel panic. I'm not sure what more I can do about it. I feel like I need better help than randomly looking through configurations and hoping I will learn. I'd rather have the linux running and making programs for it.

Comment: Did you make the file 'rootfs.cpio' or something, in your directory ' output/images/'  by 'Buildroot' ?

Comment: I get kernel panic - not syncing when trying to boot.

Comment: It is the archive of root file system. You must add this file to your kernel image, for example, by using 'Initramfs source file(s)'. Doesn't it succeed?

Comment: I can add `rootfs.cpio` in menuconfig and build the vmlinux. But then `Warning: unable to open an initial console.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1772K (c022f000 - c03ea000)
This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100

---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100

random: crng init done`

Comment: About this warning 'Warning: unable to open an initial console.', do you have the /dev/console node file or something in your root file system?

Comment: I think I have no file system. I'm just getting started. There is no `/dev`

Comment: Can't you check the contents of 'rootfs.cpio'?
And please refer to the site 'https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_dev_management' for  /dev management.

Comment: It looks like a compressed file system alright when I extract it. I'm going to rebuild it and see what happens.

Comment: I'm guessing that maybe the missing of console will kill the init task, because 'init'  will evoke the shell program. And good night. It's 10.00PM in Japan.

Comment: Domo arigatou gozaimasu. I'm rebuilding from buildroot and exploring different configurations. Some day it will work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You forgot to give it a valid root= parameter on the command line and forgot to set the major/minor default root when you compiled your kernel. The major/minor setting doesn't work when cross compiling unless you hexedit your kernel after so you really need to pass the root= parameter.</strike>

No partitions found. Where is your initrd?

If `/init` is not found in initrd or it ever terminates, the initrd is unmounted and the rootfs is mounted.

Comment: I don't think that I have a file system. I have an SD card that might work. I should rt*m I suppose how to create a file system with Nios 2 and this FPGA.

Comment: With no filesystem and no initrd the kernel won't do anything.